# slim русская документация

Tags: php, документация, slim

Где можно найти русскую документацию по slim php микрофреймворку?

Answer (score 3):

вот присоеденяйтесь [русская дока по slim](http://slimframework.ru) перевод можно дополнять

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте это посмотреть, может пригодится:

- https://webformyself.com/urok-1-vvedenie-v-frejmvork-php-slim-ustanovka/
- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD-piGJ3Dtl0PaulQMWLnNKct-L8sa6pw
- [http://artemdemo.me/blog/создание-rest-api-сервера-на-slim-php-фреймворк-вид/](http://artemdemo.me/blog/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-rest-api-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-slim-php-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4/)

Или так:

- https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=ru&sl=en&tl=ru&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.slimframework.com%2Fdocs%2F